# How to convert a datetime ''May 30 2022 9:30PM" to this "2022-05-30 21:30:00" in Snowflake SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a date column in text format of "May 30 2022 9:30PM"  and it needs to convert to "2022-05-30 21:30:00" in Snowflake SQL

I tried below SQL and its not working.

```
SELECT cast('May 30 2022 9:30PM' as datetime);
```

Comment: Snowflake <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Snowflake, try the following:

```
select to_timestamp_ntz('May 30 2022 9:30PM', 'MON DD YYYY HH12:MIAM');
```

Reference:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html